# Exibir input dependendo do login - PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde, tenho um formulário com alguns `inputs`, quero exibir somente 1 `input` a cada **login** diferente ao estar logado no sistema, pensei em utilizar `IF` e `ELSE`, mas não estou sabendo usar, alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou tentando assim:

```
    <?php

$codigo_relatorio = $_GET['codigo_relatorio'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM relatorio WHERE codigo_relatorio = '$codigo_relatorio' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    if($cont['login'] == "educacao.fisica"){

    echo'

    <div class=form-group>
    <label for=file-multiple-input class= form-control-label> <b>Educação Física - Arquivo:</b></b></label>
    <a style='color: Blue' href=uploads/uploadsed/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?><?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?></a>

    <input type=file id=file-multiple-input name=fileed multiple= class=form-control-file >'; 

    }else{ }

    </div> ?>
```

Continua sendo exibido a todos os logins...

**EDIT : Acho que estou no caminho, aonde estou errando???**

```
<?php 
$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE login ='$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
{  $class = $cont['class'];}

$codigo_relatorio = $_GET['codigo_relatorio'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM relatorio WHERE codigo_relatorio = '$codigo_relatorio' ");
while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {


   if ($class == "adm") 
    {

echo '

      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file-multiple-input" class=" form-control-label"> <b>Educação Física - Arquivo:</b></b></label>
      <a style='color: Blue' href="uploads/uploadsed/<?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?>"><?php echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'];?></a>

      <input type="file" id="file-multiple-input" name="fileed" multiple="" class="form-control-file" >
      </div>

        ';
  }
?>
```

Comment: O que tem em `$cont` ?

Comment: Está ai @PedroHenrique.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php Procure dar mais detalhes das entradas e saídas que espera em seu algorítimo.

Comment: Olá, você não poderia criar uma coluna em login como por exemplo o nome "permissão" e tipo INT e definir os logins por números de permissão, então na busca no banco de dados retornar esse numero de permissão e então mostrar o login desejado.

Comment: Samuel, coloque os esquemas das tabelas envolvidas mais uma amostra de dados. Sem conhecer essas tabelas não posso lhe ajudar com certeza, posso até dar uma resposta mas seria um chute.

Comment: @AugustoVasques [Isso ajuda?](https://prnt.sc/r1cjwi)